# iOS Universal Links in Adobe AIR - documentation?

Tags: ios, air, adobe

The [official Adobe documentation page](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/flashruntimes/articles/universal-links-for-ios.html) for using iOS Universal Links in Adobe AIR is broken -- presumably a change in website formatting has removed critical implementation info.

There are no "steps" to follow, no code snippets detailing what to put in your application descriptor, and no sample `apple-app-site-association` JSON file.

**Q) With the official site broken, where can I find this documentation?**

Note: contrast to the [Android App Links documentation](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-app-links.html), which has all relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

I've recovered the page via the [web.archive.org backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20170702233040/https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/flashruntimes/articles/universal-links-for-ios.html) -- but that's relatively slow. So I've reproduced this missing content below. The [Apple Universal Links doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) is also helpful defining the specifications for your `apple-app-site-association` JSON file, and this [medium article](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/everything-you-need-to-know-about-implementing-ios-and-android-mobile-deep-linking-f4348b265b49) is a nice overview of the Universal Links in general.

---

### Introduction

With iOS 9, Apple introduced a deep linking feature known as Universal Links. If your application supports Universal Links, iOS 9 users can be redirected to your application just by tapping a link to your website. Universal Links let you replace custom URL schemes with standard HTTP or HTTPS links.

Previously, in order to launch an application through browser, we used custom URL schemes. With iOS 9, there are some restrictions to custom URL schemes. For example: 
For an application XYZ to be able to launch an application ABC, you need to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to the info.plist of ABC specifying the URL schemes of XYZ and any other applications that you would like ABC to to open.

Alternatively with iOS9, you can use the Universal Links feature to accomplish this task. Universal Links work for all users, if the users have your app installed; the link takes them directly into your app. If they don’t have your app installed, the link opens your website in Safari.

### How AIR supports Universal Links

To create an AIR application with Universal Links, you need to follow the below steps:

### 1) Application Descriptor file

Add the entitlements in your `app.xml` file as shown below.

```
<iPhone>
  <Entitlements> 
  <![CDATA[ 
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key> 
    <array>
      <string>applinks:www.exampledomain.com</string>
    </array>
  ]]> 
  </Entitlements> 
</iPhone>
```

**Points to note:**

- Associated domains should be enabled in your provisioning profile for Universal Links to work.
- `www.exampledomain.com` should be replaced with your website address.

### 2) apple-app-site-association JSON file

When the users install your app, iOS checks this file on your web server to make sure that your website allows your app to open URLs on its behalf. Only you can create and upload this file, so the association of your website with your app is secure.

Create a JSON format file with the content as shown below.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": {
      "LKRHPA3TAK.com.exampledomain.app": {
        "paths":[ "*" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Points to note:**

- The apps key in an `apple-app-site-association` file is required and should be an empty array.
- The value of the details key is an array of dictionaries; one dictionary per application that your website supports. The order of the dictionaries in the array determines the order that the system follows when looking for a match.
- Each application-specific dictionary contains an appID (here, it is `LKRHPA3TAK.com.exampledomain.app`) and a paths key.
- The value of the appID key is the application’s team ID (here, it is `LKRHPA3TAK`) and the bundle ID (here, it is `com.exampledomain.app`).
- The value of the paths key is an array of strings that specify the paths of your website that are supported by the application.
- The website paths specified here are case-sensitive.
- The JSON file should not be added to the file name (simply keep it as apple-app-site-association).
- The JSON file should be signed using the openssl command and certificate from iOS trusted authority. See [Shared Web Credentials Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/) for details.
- This file should be uploaded to the root of your HTTPS web server.

To invoke your application through the browser, you need to enter the Universal Link of your application in the browser. The same can be received in your ActionScript code by registering for NativeApplication invokeEvent. For example:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, invokeHandler)
```

### References

[Release Notes | Flash Player® 19 AIR® 19](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_19_air_19_release_notes.html)

**Apple Documentation**

- [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)
- [Adopting Handoff](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html)
- [Shared Web Credentials Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/)
- [Launch Services Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html)

**Known Issue**

- [4042131] An extra `InvokeEvent` is received with arguments array as null.